# Performance Testing_JMeter

Tags: regex, string, jmeter, string-comparison

I am new to jMeter, In my application i am having "source" and "destination" dropdown boxes in this i need to generate a random value each time and if both the "source and destination are same" cant book the ticket,

thanks in advance,,

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help. You are expected to include what you have tried and why it doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the relevant [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to fetch all the dropdown values from the box 1. For HTML responses it is recommended to use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter). Make sure to have "Match No" set to `-1`

   As the result you should be having 2 sets of [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

   ```
   source_1=foo
   source_2=bar
   source_3=baz
   source_matchNr=3

   destination_1=foo
   destination_2=bar
   destination_3=baz
   destination_matchNr=3
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the CSS/JQuery Extractors and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables

   def randomSource = getRandomCity('source', vars)

   while (true) {
       def randomDestination = getRandomCity('destination', vars)
       if (!randomSource.equals(randomDestination)) {
           vars.put('randomSource', randomSource)
           vars.put('randomDestination', randomDestination)
           break
       }
   }

   def static getRandomCity(String prefix, JMeterVariables vars) {
       return vars.get(prefix + '_' + RandomUtils.nextInt(1, vars.get(prefix + '_matchNr') as int))
   }
   ```

   The above code will create the following JMeter Variables:

   - `${randomSource}`
   - `${randomDestination}`

   which you will be able to use where required. The exact setup might be different, however idea should still be the same. See